# Repeating definitions in the Abstract in the Introduction?

Tags: mathematics, abstract, introduction

In a mathematics paper that has an *Abstract* immediately followed by an
*Introduction* section, should notation that is defined in the Abstract be
repeated in the Introduction?
Or is it fair to assume the reader will read both consecutively,
and such repetition is superfluous?
For example,

> *Abstract.*
> This paper studies the cut locus C(x) of ...

> *Introduction.*
> We let C(x) designate the cut locus of ...

Comment: More generally: a paper should always be written so that it is complete and readable even if the abstract were not present at all.

Comment: @GregMartin This should be an answer.

Comment: Thank you for making this question independent of its title :)

Comment: Personally, I like to keep the abstract free of formulas and references, if possible. Defining a notation in the introduction of the article, rather than in its abstract seems more reasonable in this respect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think the body of the paper needs the full definition. The abstract might not. If you can write it without formulas it will be easier to read and easier for tools to parse and tag. So

> This paper studies the cut locus of [continue with appropriate words]

would be better if it's possible.

Comment: I would go so far as to give a precise definition of "cut locus" in the paper. Researchers from other universities or other countries can easily have a somewhat-similar-but-subtly-different-definition, and not stating the definition you're using in your paper just obfuscates your paper by forcing the readers to guess.

Answer (score 7):

The abstract should entice you to read the paper.  I’m not sure how including definitions fits this goals, unless you have a very long abstract.

Comment: I'm not sure about "entice" (we're not selling cars), but the abstract should summarize what you're doing in a clear and concise way to allow the reader to rapidly decide whether the material is likely to interest them or not and worth devoting more time to.  If a definition helps that then I think a definition is useful.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine well...  You may not be selling cars but you are selling your results.  (Not sure about "selling" but close enough to reality). I would not state that the objective is to allow the reader to decide whether "the material" is of interest to them: I would suggest instead it is to allow the reader to decide whether *the results* are of interest to them, and I'm not sure how a definition helps with that.

Comment: As, perhaps focusing on the *results* is a better description, although I think some people will be more interested if the *approach* is a method that interests them.  *"We got this result by using this approach"* sort of thing ?  And, as always, it's important to drop the word "novel" in there somewhere to wake the reviewer up. :-)

Comment: An abstract is a summary, not an advertisement.

Comment: @CrisLuengo …and products should sell on merits, not on the advertisement but the reality is that if you don’t try to catch the attention of the prospective readers there will be that many fewer people to read your papers.